# how to chain queryset mixin for django rest viewsets?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-rest-viewsets

I need to write the following querysets mixins:

```
class VendorOwnedQuerySetMixin(models.QuerySet):
    def get_objects_for_vendor(self, request):
        vendor_user = VendorUserModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        return qs.filter(vendor=vendor_user.vendor)


class OrganizationOwnedQuerySetMixin(object):
    def get_objects_for_organization(self, request):
        return self.filter(organization__domains__name=hostname_from_request(request))
```

All's working well because some model managers will inherit the first mixin and some inherit the second.

Then inside the `get_queryset` of the viewset, i will call the appropriate get_objects method.

example

```
def get_queryset(self, queryset=None):
        return Some.objects.get_objects_for_organization(self.request)
```

Now I need to have a django rest viewset that needs to run the `get_queryset` method that runs both filters.

How do I "chain" them within the `get_queryset` method? Because I want to reuse my code where possible

Answer (score 1):

In order to chain the filters, you need to get the previous queryset. This can be achieved by calling `super().get_queryset(request)`. It will get the queryset from the other classes your view inherit from and will apply the filter:

```
class VendorOwnedQuerySetMixin(models.QuerySet):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        vendor_user = VendorUserModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
        return qs.filter(vendor__user=vendor_user.vendor)


class OrganizationOwnedQuerySetMixin(object):
    def get_objects_for_organization(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(organization__domains__name=hostname_from_request(request)
```

Remember that you **MUST** set the mixins **before** the view in order to work. For example:

```
class MyView(OrganizationOwnedQuerySetMixin, VendorOwnedQuerySetMixin, RetrieveAPIView):
    ...
```

A call on `get_queryset` will get the `RetrieveAPIView` queryset which will get passed to `VendorOwnedQuerySetMixin` once the `super()` call returns, get the filter applied and returns the result to `OrganizationOwnedQuerySetMixin` after the `super()` is called which in turn will apply its filter and return the result.